# Can't run php bin/console in symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I'm new on symfony, after following instruction to install it, it said i have to run:

```
bin/console server:run
```

i type it on my symfony instalation folder. but i got error:

```
Could not open input file: bin/console
```

and then i'm searching the answer in here and it told me to run app/console

```
bin/console server:run
```

but it just got the same problem. is it i miss some bin folder here or something? since i can't see bin folder or app folder on my project root folder. here's my project folder structure:
[image]

Comment: Why do you expect that something happens? `bin/console`  does not exist after all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You obviously cloned a Git repo, which does not contain all Symfony framework components.

You have to create symfony project through
symfony installer http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html

or

with composer `composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition my_project_name`.

Comment: i run using "symfony new my_project_name" is it any different?

Comment: "symfony new my_project_name" is the correct way to install with Symfony installer, but your project's folder structure does not correspond to this type of installation. Check the link I posted above and follow the instructions step-by-step